# Using deployR with Python

Tags: python, r, deployr

We are planning to use [deployR](https://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/) behind a Python server. The official documentation suggests looking at the core api to do this.

Are there any examples of using deployR with Python? A github repository or blog would be helpful.

Comment: You just introduced me to DeployR! I also work with python servers; I obviously can't contribute my experience here, but I'd also love to hear an answer.